# Mysql -  connect to remote server using IP address

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and MySQL to make a database connection, the only change is that I am trying to access my remote server from my local computer using my server IP address.

```
mysql_connect("x.xx.xx.x","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
```

and the error I am getting is `Unable to connect to the given host`. The user has all privileges and rights.

Comment: is your server accessible from your computer? Especially the MYSQL server port?

Comment: try connecting manually from a terminal, that will indicate where the problem is.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most default installs of MySQL only listen to the local machine.

Look for the `bind-address` setting in `my.cnf` on the server, and make sure it's listening on the IP address you're targetting. You may also need to ensure `skip-networking` *isn't* switched on!

Alternatively (and less securely!) the following will set it up to listen on all addresses - local and remote:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Thank all of you for great help let me try all this and believe this will solve my problem

Answer (score 4):

Try to add a user (USER-NAME) allowed to connect from the IP:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO USER-NAME@IP IDENTIFIED BY "PASSWORD";
```

USER-NAME is the username that you would like to create (like 'widor') 
IP is the public IP address of your remote connection (like '195.x.y.z')

Of course, limit the privileges you want to grant (ALL PRIVILEGES is probably not your choice)

Comment: 6 years later and this has been super useful, I had everything setup correctly, just didn't give the user access to everything I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Before you try using PHP todo this. Open up your terminal or console and type the following:

> $ mysql -u username -h x.xx.xx.x -p

then enter your password

Or on windows then type:

> \path\to\mysql.exe -u username -h x.xx.xx.x -p

then enter your password

This will give you a more detailed response as to the authentication issue that's coming up. And you can be 100% sure that your remote login from your IP address works. If it works fine then its something in your PHP code that you're missing.

Answer (score 2):

1) Check which interface MySQL listen for connections, local (localhost, 127.0.0.1) or remote (0.0.0.0 or IP address). It's in my.cnf. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

2) Check does your user have corresponding privileges. User that logs in from localhost can have different priveleges from remote one. For example 'user'@'localhost' and 'user'@'%'