# Connecting to local mysql database from php web application through internet

Tags: php, mysql

How can i connect to a mysql database hosted in a LAN from a PHP web application through internet

Comment: What do you mean by that? can you explain further?

Comment: I have a mysql database in a local machine, i want to access it from website

Comment: It isn't possible unless you have a static IP address. And if you do own a static IP, follow this link here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754757/mysql-connect-to-remote-server-using-ip-address

Comment: Apologies, but IMHO I think it is obvious what is being asked. He was PHP website which needs to access a MySQL database which resides on a non-public facing server accessible from the PHP server via an internal (LAN) ip. But when the web app runs it resolves the mySQL server IP as another external address.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the database is on a PC and that the router is routing external requests through to that PC. Then ensure that the database has the right user permissions set up to return data to a request that isn't originating from `@'localhost'` and you should be sweet. You will probably need to have a static IP to make things easier to connect to from the outside as well.

Comment: Short question: `Ensure that the database is on a PC`. Where else cold it be m8? :)

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you keep your mysql installation up to date. And should you not be able to acquire a static IP, services like dyndns can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a static IP address, you can simply connect directly to the database server:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'username', 'password', 'database');
```

If you don't have a static IP address, you may or may not be able to rely on that.

On dial-up (!) connections, you will probably have a different IP address every time. If you have broadband, it depends. My IP address has stayed the same for months and months.

If you have a 'dynamic' IP address, then you cannot completely trust that it will always be the same. If you pay extra for a static one, you can be sure it won't change.

Answer (score -1):

You will need a webhosting to host it to internet.

Answer (score -1):

my suggestion is get a web host to host the database. It is much cheaper and less trouble and almost no configuration. You could then upload your database. It is an option though.