# Changed $dbHost from hostname to ip address, and now I'm getting connection errors. Are they not interchangeable?

Tags: php

The only change I made was

```
$dbHost = <hostname>
```

to

```
$dbHost = <ipaddress>
```

and now it's giving me connection errors.

Error:

```
Database Connection Error 
A failure occurred attempting to connect to the database. 

This could be caused by a temporary network failure, but it's more likely that this is the result of incorrect database connection parameters specified at the time WebEvent was installed. 

Please contact your site administrator for assistance in diagnosing this problem.
```

Comment: It depends a lot on your system setup, not MySQL. Does connecting to that IP through the MySQL shell work?

Comment: Assuming @swl1020 is using MySQL...

Comment: maybe your mysql setup restricts you to connect only via localhost,this is the default setting in many installations   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754757/mysql-connect-to-remote-server-using-ip-address

Comment: the difference between localhost and a sites public ip are different... they go through different interfaces

Comment: Try adding the port number after the ip address, such as:  [ip_address]:3306  3306 is the default mysql port

Comment: You can check connection in command line: `mysql -h <ipaddress> -p 3306` or even `telnet <ipaddress> 3306` :)