# Mysql Connection of database on different IP

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

How to connect to a MySql database if I have IP address,Username and Password of the admin and I want to connect it on my personal MySql workbench?

`Unable to connect to the given host` I'm getting this error even after Granting all privilages by taking reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7754844/20218893)

Comment: Have you confirmed you're able to reach the destination host and port?  For example, if you do `telnet <destination ip> 3306` does the connection get established?